# Formas de testar diretamente uma função interna

Tags: javascript, testes

Suponhamos que temos a seguinte função closure e gostaríamos de testar a função interna com Jest.

**Função closure em primeira mão feita por mim:**

```js
function ModuleCharacterCounter() {   

    function characteCounter(nome) {
        return `O nome ${nome} possui ${count(nome)} letras`;  
    }  

    function count(nome) {     
        return nome.length;  
    }

    return {     
        start(nome) {
            return characteCounter(nome);
        }    
    };
    
}

var counter = ModuleCharacterCounter();
console.log(counter.start('José'));
```

Estudando a documentação descobri que posso testar o módulo com Jest, mas nada como testar funções privadas.

**Teste do módulo:**´

```js
let {ModuleCharacterCounter} = require('../arquivo.js')

describe("Character Counter", () => {
    test("testantdo", () => {
        let counter = ModuleCharacterCounter();
        expect(counter.start('José')).toEqual( "O nome José possui 4 letras");
    });
});
```

Não convencido eu revirei github e encontrei esse repositório https://github.com/bahmutov/test-mole de 7 anos atrás. Com um pouco de código a mais, acabei conseguindo testar a função interna.

**Teste função interna:**

```js
if (typeof require === 'function') {
    require('test-mole');
    require('lazy-ass');
}

(function ModuleCharacterCounter() {   

    function characteCounter(nome) {
        return `O nome ${nome} possui ${count(nome)} letras`;  
    }

    function count(nome) {     
        return nome.length;  
    }

    testMole.it('Testando função count', function () {
        lazyAss(count('José'), 4);
    });

    return {     
        start(nome) {
            return characteCounter(nome);
        }    
    };
    
}());
```

Por fim, existe alternativas ao test-mole? É possível testar função interna com jest, ou foi eu que não entendi a documentação?

Comment: Acredito que a questão aqui seja um buraco um pouco mais embaixo, talvez a reflexão "Devo testar meus métodos privados?". Em tese, minha opinião é que você não deve, pois você está testando ele indiretamente pela parte pública, se não está, aquele código é inutilizado/não coberto.
No seu caso por exemplo ele está sendo coberto pela chamada ao método público. Aqui estão alguns links sobre a questão
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34586/10880357
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52054/10880357

Comment: O título é _Formas de testar diretamente uma função interna_ e na pergunta você fala de _closure_, e pelo que eu entendi, você quer testar uma função interna que é um closure de forma direta e por fora, é isso mesmo?

Comment: Sim, me corrige se eu estiver errado, mas acho que closure no caso seria uma função(tipo de um módulo) que encapsula, tornando algumas funções internas privadas, não é?

Comment: Olha, nesse caso acredito que seria melhor você testar essas funções através da publica. Existe um pacote que se chama [rewire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire), ela testa funções privadas, aquelas que não foram exportadas não sei se ela consegue testar funções internas.

Comment: Não, closure é apenas uma instancia de função que captura um escopo léxico. Não é módulo e nem controle de acesso. Esse é só um caso de uso onde se aplica-se closures para emular métodos privados

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar console.assert direto na closure.

Outra vantagem é que você não precisa de nenhuma lib externa e os blocos console podem ser facilmente ignorado na hora de buildar.

```
function ModuleCharacterCounter() {   

    function characteCounter(nome) {
        return `O nome ${nome} possui ${count(nome)} letras`;  
    }  

    function count(nome) {     
        return nome.length;  
    }
    console.assert(count('José') === 6); //esse vai aparecer no console pq a asserção falhou
    console.assert(count('José') === 4); //nada vai acontecer pq o teste passou


    return {     
        start(nome) {
            return characteCounter(nome);
        }    
    };
    
}

var counter = ModuleCharacterCounter();
console.log(counter.start('José'));
```